# Getting pywin32 excelAddin.py working on Windows XP Microsoft Excel 2007

Tags: python, excel, windows-xp, add-in, pywin32

I'm trying to get a demo script on Windows XP for Microsoft Office Excel 2007 using python 2.5.4 with pywin32 from here: [Python for Windows Extensions](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/)

Though the Com add-in registers itself successfully and is displayed in "com add-ins" list in Excel, it does not work.

Only error feedback I get is on the "Load behavior" line in excel's "com add-ins" dialog, says "Not loaded. A `runtime` error occurred during the loading of the com add-in"

Does `excel` or `office, log anywhere on the system? How can I find out what goes wrong?

Comment: Which Python version do you use?  Python 2.6.x may have problems with COM servers because of issues loading the MSVCR90 C runtime dll.  Can you try with Python 2.5?

Comment: ops forgot to mention, i'm using python 2.5.4